# What has to be Glib::init()'ed in order to use Glib::wrap?

Tags: c++, gtk, glib, gtksourceview

So I'm trying to make use of a GtkSourceView in C++ using [GtkSourceViewmm](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceviewmm/), whose documentation and level of support give me the impression that it hasn't been very carefully looked at in a long time. But I'm always an optimist :)

I'm trying to add a [SourceView](http://projects.gnome.org/gtksourceviewmm/classgtksourceview_1_1SourceView.html) using some code similar to the following:

```
 Glib::RefPtr<gtksourceview::SourceLanguageManager> source_language_manager = gtksourceview::SourceLanguageManager::create();
 Glib::RefPtr<gtksourceview::SourceLanguage> source_language = Glib::wrap(gtk_source_language_manager_guess_language(source_language_manager->gobj(), file, NULL));
 Glib::RefPtr<gtksourceview::SourceBuffer> source_buffer = gtksourceview::SourceBuffer::create(source_language);
 gtksourceview::SourceView* = m_source_view = new gtksourceview::SourceView(source_buffer);

 m_vbox.pack_start(*m_source_view);
```

Unfortunately, it spits out the warning

> (algoviz:4992): glibmm-WARNING **:
>   Failed to wrap object of type
>   'GtkSourceLanguage'. Hint: this error
>   is commonly caused by failing to call
>   a library init() function.

and when I look at it in a debugger, indeed the second line above (the one with the `Glib::wrap()`) is returning `NULL`. I have no idea why this is, but I tried to heed the warning by adding `Glib::init()` to the begining of the program, but that didn't seem to help at all either.

I've tried Google'ing around, but have been unsuccessful. Does anyone know what Glib wants me to init in order to be able to make that wrap call? Or, even better, does anyone know of any working sample code that uses GtkSourceViewmm (not just regular GtkSourceView)? I haven't been able to find any actual sample code, not even on Google Code Search.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out, perhaps not surprisingly, that what I needed to init was:

```
gtksourceview::init();
```

After this, I ran into another problem with one of the parameter to `gtksourceview::SourceLanguageManager`, but this was caused by a genuine bug which I [subsequently reported](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=624269) and was promptly fixed. So everything's working great now!

Comment: This changes to Gsv::init() for newer versions.

Comment: to use Gsv::init(), you need to include gtksourceviewmm.h

Answer (score 0):

I use gtkmm. Typically you have to initialize things with something like :

```
_GTKMain = new Gtk::Main(0, 0, false);
```

Of course do not forget :

```
delete _GTKMain;
```

Check  here for details :

http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtkmm/2.19/classGtk_1_1Main.html

(Sorry but the link option does not work ...)